# jcarousel how to vertically center items

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3, jcarousel

I'm taking over maintenance of an ASP.NET MVC 3 C# Razor website that uses jQuery (all new technologies for me).  My items in my jcarousel are thumbnails of various sizes.  I would like them to be centered vertically in the carousel, but I have not been able to figure out how to make that happen.

I tried following putting `vertical-align: middle;` in various places, but to no effect.  I imagine the problem is I'm very new to web development and am missing something obvious, but I've been at it a couple hours so am finally asking help from this brilliant community!

How can I get my images centered vertically in the carousel?

Here's my code in my view:

```
<ul id="screenshot-carousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
  @{ string[,] screenshots = ViewBag.Screenshots; }
  @for (int i = 0; i < screenshots.GetLength(0); i++)
  {
    <li><a class="screenshot" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/map-creator/" + screenshots[i, 0] + ".jpg")" title="@screenshots[i, 1]">
      <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/map-creator/" + screenshots[i, 0] + "_t.jpg")" width="@screenshots[i, 2] " height="@screenshots[i, 3] " alt="@screenshots[i, 1]" /></a></li>
  }
</ul>
@section HtmlHead
{
  <style type="text/css">
/**
 * Overwrite for having a carousel with dynamic width.
 */
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
    width: 85%;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width: 100%;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

    a.screenshot img {
      border: 1px solid #aaa;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#screenshot-carousel').jcarousel();

          $(".screenshot").colorbox({
              rel: 'screenshot',
              width: "1200",
              height: "600",
              current: "{current} of {total}"
          });
      });    
  </script>
```

And here's the non-button carousel stuff in jcarousel\tango\skin.css (note that some of these appear also in the code in the view, I assume that means the code in the view overrides this code):

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
    background: #F0F6F9;
    border: 1px solid #346F97;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
    width: 245px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-vertical {
    width: 75px;
    height: 245px;
    padding: 40px 20px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width:  245px;
    height: 75px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-vertical {
    width:  75px;
    height: 245px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-vertical {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-placeholder {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm leaving my other answer in case it helps someone, but I've found a better answer now that works on IE10 and Chrome (though the centering may not be perfect on Chrome, it's close enough for me). Instead of the setting the `line-height` and the `vertical-align` properties, in my img I set the appropriate top margin, which is (LARGEST_IMAGE_HEIGHT - IMAGE_HEIGHT) / 2.  I calculate that value in my controller and pass the value in to the view for each image.

So the fix in the view is adding the style to the img element:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/map-creator/" + screenshots[i, 0] + "_t.jpg")" width="@screenshots[i, 2]" alt="@screenshots[i, 1]" style="margin-top:@screenshots[i, 4]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following css in my view file, and it works on Chrome.  Setting the line-height and the vertical-align seem to be what did it.  Still doesn't work on IE10, so I'm beginning to think it's impossible for IE10.  If anyone has a better answer, please post and I'll accept it instead of mine!

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item {
    width: auto;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 80px;
}

a.screenshot img {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is rather old and even jcarousel has changed significantly, but I would recommend good ol' `display: table-cell`.

```
ul#screenshot-carousel {
    display: table;
    width: auto;
}

ul#screenshot-carousel &gt; li {
    display: table-cell;
    vartical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Only works on Chrome in windows. You can't set the li to table-cell since it's floated.

Comment: haven't tried it, @dannio, but... why can't you apply it even if it's floated "by default"? The purpose of applying a different value for the property than the default one is just to change its default behaviour...

Comment: I tried it on firefox and it says that due to the element being floated, setting it to display: table-cell would have no effect. The way I got it to work was to set it like this:
ul:{ display: flex; height: 100%}
li:{display: flex; align-items: center;}